# What is the error in my fibonacci logic

Tags: java, data-structures

I am using below method to get fabonacci number series upto 100(based on user input), but the output contains some negative junk number.

```
public static void getIterativeFibonacci(int number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
    int fibo1 = 1, fibo2 = 1, fibonacci = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
        fibonacci = fibo1 + fibo2;
        fibo1 = fibo2;
        fibo2 = fibonacci;
        if (fibonacci <= number) {
            System.out.println("==>"+fibonacci);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to find out the issue in above logic.

## UPDATE:

I got the fix:

```
public static void getIterativeFibonacci(long number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
    long fibo1 = 1, fibo2 = 1, fibonacci = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
        fibonacci = fibo1 + fibo2;
        if (fibonacci >= number) {
            break;
        }
        fibo1 = fibo2;
        fibo2 = fibonacci;
        System.out.println("==>" + fibonacci);
    }
}
```

Comment: Output : 100 
==>2
==>3
==>5
==>8
==>13
==>21
==>34
==>55
==>89

Comment: There are two "fixes" in your code - changing the parameter type to `long` and `break`ing the loop. Which one is the fix, or is it both?

Answer (score 1):

Break the for loop once you reached the number limit.

```
public static void getIterativeFibonacci(int number) {
        if (number == 1) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
        int fibo1 = 1, fibo2 = 0, fibonacci = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            fibonacci = fibo1 + fibo2;
            fibo1 = fibo2;
            fibo2 = fibonacci;
            if (fibonacci <= number) {
                System.out.println("==>"+fibonacci);
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getIterativeFibonacci(int number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
    int fibo1 = 0, fibo2 = 1, fibonacci = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
        System.out.print(fibo1)
        fibonacci = fibo1 + fibo2;
        fibo1 = fibo2;
        fibo2 = fibonacci;
    if (fibonacci <= number) {
        System.out.println("==>"+fibonacci);
    }
}
```

}

try this one